# php xml XPath foreach returning all nodes instead of iterating

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a XML file like this

```
<Articles>
 <Article>
  <ArticleTitle> 
   First Book
 </ArticleTitle>
</Article>
 <Article>
  <ArticleTitle> 
   Second Book
 </ArticleTitle>
</Article>
```

And using this type of php script to retrieve the contents of ArticleTitle in an iterative fashion

```
foreach ($xml->Article as $Article){
$title = $Article->xpath('//ArticleTitle');
echo $title[0];
}
```

But this displays

```
First Book
First Book
```

Instead of

```
First Book
Second Book
```

I was assuming that when the `foreach ($xml->Article as $Article)` starts it will grab each Article node and then I can access the contents of that node but this is not what is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the xpath you have used is an absolute path (it starts with `/`) so the fact that you are calling it from a child node has no effect. You should use a relative path, in this case either simply `ArticleTitle` will suffice or `.//ArticleTitle` to allow for other nodes between `Article` and `ArticleTitle`. For example:

```
foreach ($xml->Article as $Article){
    $title = $Article->xpath('ArticleTitle');
    echo $title[0];
}

foreach ($xml->Article as $Article){
    $title = $Article->xpath('.//ArticleTitle');
    echo $title[0];
}
```

Output in both cases is:

```
First Book
Second Book
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2pDcj)

Answer (score 1):

This should work too with your original XPath expression :

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Articles>
<Article>
<ArticleTitle>First Book</ArticleTitle>
</Article>
<Article>
<ArticleTitle>Second Book</ArticleTitle>
</Article>
</Articles>
XML;
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$elements = $xpath->query('//ArticleTitle');
foreach($elements as $element)
echo ($element->nodeValue), "\n";
?>
```

Output :

```
First Book
Second Book
```